# Adding debit or credit card programmatically into Google Wallet

Tags: android, android-pay

if we have a credit or debit card information, could we add credit or debit card programmatically into Google Wallet either from Android app or server code?

Comment: Do you solved your problem for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and IMHO, that would be counter to what Wallet Instant Buy, is all about.

> **Q: Why have Virtual Onetime Card numbers?**
>
> - **Increased security**: If the one-time card number is compromised, a fraudulent user can do little or no damage. *Google users expect Google to not share their real financial information.*
> - **Simplified technical integration**: sharing Virtual Onetime Card numbers allows Google to dramatically simplify merchant integration (eliminating complex encryption, dedicated keys, direct connection between Google and merchant's data bunkers, etc.)

You're probably looking for/comparing with other credit card processing gateway/services which do have options for such (e.g. store and "tokenize"). Wallet Instant Buy isn't such - [see this FAQ](https://developers.google.com/wallet/instant-buy/faq).

Hth...

Answer (score 0):

If you are the card issuer, then yes, you can. This is called in-app provisioning for Apple Pay, or push-provisioning for Google Pay.

You will find the related documentation for Android here : https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/apis/push-provisioning/android.